# Statsd - Graphite Data points resets to zero

Tags: metrics, graphite, statsd, collectd

I'm using graphite, when i send the metric stats_count it shows up in the metrics data points json, but after some time it resets to zero.

ex:
initially [0, 1426770240] [449.968673, 1426770300]
later [0, 1426770240]  [0, 1426770300] [0, 1426770360]

retentions = 10s:7d,5m:30d,15m:5y

Answer (score 0):

You're likely using a wrong aggregation function in Graphite, so it's aggregating your counts by averaging them instead of summing them up.

From https://kevinmccarthy.org/blog/2013/07/18/10-things-i-learned-deploying-graphite/#aggregating-data-what:

> The other thing that can trip you up is aggregating counts. What
>   happens when we average 60 seconds of counts? Well, we lose around
>   1/60th of the events that happened. So for count statistics, we
>   actually want to sum the number of times that something happened.

Check [this section](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/graphite.md#storage-aggregation) on the statsd docs about how to configure Graphite for statsd. The key here is:

```
# conf/storage-aggregation.conf:
[count]
pattern = \.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum
```

As you can see the aggregation method used is sum. By default Graphite averages metrics when downsamping.